# Listbox with Grid as ItemPanelTemplate: Problem with SharedSizeGroup

Tags: wpf, xaml, listbox, sharedsizegroup, issharedsizescope

I have set up a `ListBox` where the items are another `ListBox`.
This allows me to bind an observable collection that contains a list.

I used an horizontal `StackPanel`as the `ItemsPanelTemplate` of the second `ListBox` but it was ugly so I tried to use a `Grid` instead (for the moment I fixed the number of columns to test if everything is working).

Everything is in the correct cell, but it looks like the `SharedSizeGroup` is not taken in account, what I would like is that the cells of the same columns have the same width (the one of the widest element)

See picture of what is happenning with my XAML code:

[image: The items of the inner ListBoxes do not share size groups.]

And what I would like to achieve

[image: The items of the inner ListBoxes share size groups and are aligned.]

I think that I did not place the `Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True"` to the proper place or maybe I did something else wrong.

I know this looks like a `DataGrid` for now, but in the next step some lines may not have the same number of items.

XAML Code

```
<ListBox Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding LibraryGroupedValuesList}"
                SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedGroupedValues}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Position}" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                    </TextBlock>
                    <ListBox Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True" Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{Binding PositionValues}" 
                        ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource VariableTypeTemplateSelector}"
                        HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" >
                        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                <Grid>
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" SharedSizeGroup="1"></ColumnDefinition>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" SharedSizeGroup="2"></ColumnDefinition>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" SharedSizeGroup="3"></ColumnDefinition>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" SharedSizeGroup="4"></ColumnDefinition>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" SharedSizeGroup="5"></ColumnDefinition>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                </Grid>
                            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                        <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                            <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                                <Style.Setters>
                                    <Setter Property="Grid.Column" Value="{Binding Index}"/>
                                </Style.Setters>
                            </Style>
                        </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                    </ListBox>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an outer `ListBox` that contains items which are itself `ListBox`es, which have a `Grid` as `ItemsPanel`. This `Grid` defines shared size groups. Putting the `Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True"` attached property on the inner `ListBox` does not work, because this scope only contains a **single** `Grid`, the items panel. The way it is right now means each inner `ListBox` with its **own** `Grid` as items panel defines its own shared size scope, which does not affect the others. This would work if you had e.g. an `ItemTemplate` containing a `Grid`, since then each item *inside* the `ListBox` and hence *inside* the shared size scope would be targeted.

This is also implies the solution to your issue, just move the shared size scope declaration to the outer `ListBox`, which is the scope containing all inner `ListBox`es an their `Grid`s.

```
<ListBox Grid.Row="1"
         ItemsSource="{Binding LibraryGroupedValuesList}"
         SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedGroupedValues}"
         Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True">
```

Comment: thanks, it was too big for me to see.